# Does NLTK have its own Dependency Parser that gives similar results as Stanford Parser?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, dependency-tree

I want to know, does NLTK has its own Dependency Parser (I am not talking about Stanford Dependency Parser in NLTK) that produces somewhat similar results as of Stanford parser. If yes, please let me know what parser in NLTK gives similar results as NLTK has many parsers.

Thanks in advance :)